# How to use l'hopital rule?

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

So I have this question

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{x}\right)\ln\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$$

I was wondering how to solve the limit tending to 0 ? I thought of using l'Hôpital rule, but this equation is not in the form of a fraction ? What could I do ? Thanks!

Comment: You didn't attach any image

Comment: I attached it now !!

Comment: $e^{-1/x}=\frac{1}{e^{1/x}}$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Who said it's not a fraction just take the negative power to make it a fraction

Comment: But then should i multiply the ln to the fraction ? how do i proceed from there

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! Who told you L'Hospital's rule  is the panacea for limits calculation?

Comment: No one ! thats why i'am asking this question :)) otherwise i wouldn't be asking it , dont you think ?

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{x}\right)\ln\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$$
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{\ln\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)}{\exp\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}$$
so $\infty/\infty$
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{\frac{d}{dx}\ln\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)}{\frac{d}{dx}\exp\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}$$
Can you take it from there?

Comment: Yes ! but i get (-2/x) / -e^(1/x) / x²... wouldnt that still be undefined

Comment: You can simplify that to $(-2/x) / (-e^{1/x} / x^2)=(-2 x) / (-e^{1/x} ) = 2 x e^{-1/x} $, which is well-behaved

Comment: wouldnt -1/0 be undefined?

Comment: You're taking the limit for positive $x$ (indicated by the $+$ sign $x\rightarrow 0^+$), so $-1/x$ approaches $-\infty$, and $\exp(-1/x)$ approaches $\exp(-\infty)=0$

Comment: Oh okay ! so if i have a limits for a positive number, with the + sign . then it's as if x approached  negative infinity ?

Comment: No. If $x$ approaches $0$ from the positive side, $1/x$ approaches $+\infty$. If $x$ approaches $0$ from the negative side, $1/x$ approaches $-\infty$. [Just looking at a plot should make this clear](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+1%2Fx).

Answer (score 1):

You can use L'Hospital's rule here, but it's easier to substitute first.
$t=\frac{1}{x}$
$$ \lim_{t\to \infty} e^{-t} \ln(t^2) = \lim_{t\to\infty} \frac{2\ln(t)}{e^t} = \lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{\frac{2}{t}}{e^{t}} = 0 $$

Comment: Why are you putting infinity ? Wouldn it be zero ? and 2 divided by 0 divided by e to the power of 0 which is one becomes 2/0 which is undefined...

Comment: $x\to 0^+$ so $t \to \infty$

Comment: @MichaelMorello, note that $t=\frac1x$, and $\lim_{x\to0^+}{\frac1x}=\infty$

Comment: wouldnt 1 over 0 be undefined...

Comment: @MichaelMorello, $\frac{1}{0}$ is undefined, but we can take $\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{1}{x}$ which is perfectly defined and proper

Comment: why is 1 over x with the limit tending to 0+ defined?

Comment: @MichaelMorello Look in your calculus book, or on wikipedia

Comment: That's because, as $x$ gets smaller and smaller (yet positive), its reciprocal gets larger and larger.

Answer (score 0):

Needless to appeal to L'Hospital's rule.  A simple substitution $t=\dfrac1x$, and basic facts will do:
$$\mathrm e^{-\tfrac1x}\,\ln\Bigl(\frac 1{x^2}\Bigr)=\frac{2\ln t}{\mathrm e^t}\qquad(t\to +\infty\; \text{ when }\;x\to 0_+). $$
Now, near $+\infty,\;\ln t=o(t)\;$ and $\;t=o(\mathrm e^t)$, so $\;\ln t=o(\mathrm e^t)$, and the limit is $0$.

Comment: Why are you plugging in infinity ? Woulnd't you need to put 0?

Comment: $x$ tends to $0_+$, so $t$ tends to $+\infty$. Don't forget $t$ is the reciprocal of $x$.

Comment: But infinity divided by infinity is also undefined...

Comment: Yes, in general, but I used  basic *theorems* which assert that near $\infty$, $\ln t=o(t)$, &c., which means that $\lim_{t\to\infty}\dfrac{\ln t}t=0$.